# Hyperledger Fabric Network Setup on Ubuntu

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am running into issues while executing the command `./network_setup.sh up <channel_name>`. 
The error is - unknown command "channel" for "peer". I have 3 peers and none of them startup .. All 3 peers exit with the said error. Has anyone ran into this issue ?

I followed IBM marbles tutorial
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles

which redirected me to the below link and I followed the instructions mentioned in the below link.
http://fabric-rtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#all-in-one

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The link that works best for Hyperledger Fabric Alpha2 is https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/e2e_cli/end-to-end.rst

Some of the documents are outdated.

Comment: How would you save changes to a docker-container and start using that container rather than using the one which came along with the package ?

Answer (score 0):

**maybe u need to Version rollback**

- git tag
- git show {tag}
- git reset --hard {commit log}